# Solving Quadratic Recurrence Relation Modulo Prime $p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

I have a quadratic recurrence:

$$z_{n+1} = az_n^2 + bz_n + c$$

With $z_1 = 1$ and $a,b,c \geq 1$, hence all terms of the sequence are positive integers. Interestingly, according to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Examples) the recurrence has a closed-form formula for the case where

$$c = \frac {b^2-2b-8}{4a}$$

And the $n$'th term is given by $$\frac {2\alpha^{2^n} + 2\alpha^{-2^n} - b}{2a}$$

With $$\alpha=\frac{2az_1+b+\sqrt{(2az_1+b)^2-16}}{4}$$

I need to evaluate the $n$'th term modulo some prime $10^9 > p > 5$ with $n$ being too large to evaluate recursively. The closed-form formula gives correct values but it relies on high precision for $\alpha$ if $n$ is large. For my specific values of $(a,b,c)$  it turns out that $\alpha$ is not an integer, and trying to calculate the $n$'th term precisely is prone to overflows and incorrect values. Also, for this exact reason, I don't see how I can perform modular exponentiation (if it can even be done). Obviously every term in the sequence is an integer.

How can I calculate $z_n$ mod $p$ precisely for large $n$? Using either the above formula or any other way that I might miss.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading, but isn't the sequence obviously periodic $\pmod p$?  (at least eventually) There are only finitely many values $z_n$ can take and the moment you repeat, you are back in the cycle.

Comment: @lulu Yes, that is a good point. In my problem, $p$ may be large but smaller than $10^9$. With that direction, I would have to find the period of the sequence (mod $p$), denoted $\pi(p)$, and find the ($n$ mod $\pi(p)$)'th term through iteration, correct?

Comment: Iteration?  No...once you have identified the period (and the initial stub period if there is one), it's just a matter of reducing $n$ mod the period (essentially) and then looking at the cycle.  It really makes no difference at all how big $n$ is.

Comment: @lulu Can you sketch a walk-through for that approach? And possibly how to find the period?

Comment: If the sequence was just $\{1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\cdots\}$ then the only thing that matters is $n\pmod 3$.  To find the stub and cycle, just compute the first few terms of the sequence.  You are guaranteed to repeat a value within the first $p+1$ terms.

Comment: $10^9$? Are you sure you are not trying to get somebody do your work to make you look in ProjectEuler or CodeChef? Please give the source of the question!

Comment: Consider the case a=b=1.  If  we choose c=1,  such that c ≠ $\frac{b^2−2b−8}{4a}$, then $z_n$ are all integers for all n.

On the other hand, consider the case that a=1 b=5. if c = $\frac{b^2−2b−8}{4a}$, as suggested by Wiki, then $z_n$ are NOT integers for all n>0.

Comment: @Jyrki and MC from Scratch, $10^9$? Any sensible person will not try to find a sequence modulo a prime number close to 10^9! You either own a super computer or have more spare time than most people can afford.

Comment: @cdeamaze ProjectEuler often posts challenge problems involving a modulus that can be a parameter up to $10^9+7$ or some such bound. And the challenges are doable by design. Also, the recurrence takes place in the field $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, and most definitely yields elements of that field. So I don't understand why it would bother use that a characteristic zero formula yields non-integers as long as we don't attempt to divide by zero, that is we don't attempt to divide by $p$.

Comment: @Jyrki  Thanks for letting me know.  I'll avoid to take  any daunting task from now on, knowing that I have limited resource and time.  You make my day!

Answer (score 0):

Case 1,   a = b= c= 1.  c free or c ≠  $\frac{b^2−2b−8}{4a}.$

This case is recommended, as $z_n$ are all integers for all n. (See *Note below)

so that $z_n = (z_n)^2 +  z_n + 1, z_0 =1.$

We now present $z_n$ in a table and a plot

[image]

*Note that $z_n$ are all integers for all n.

[image] for all n.

Choose p=5, we have

$(z_n)_5$ = $z_n$ - floor($z_n$/5) *5

We now present $(z_n)_5$ in a table and a plot.

To be continued here

image 3

image 4

Case 2, a=1, b=5, c=7/4. c =  $\frac{b^2−2b−8}{4a}$ as suggested by Wiki.

This case is NOT recommended, as none of $z_n$ are integers except n = 0.(See

*Note below).

Next consider a=1, b=5, c=7/4 and α = 2 or 1/2,

so that $z_n = (z_n)^2 +  5z_n + 7/4, z_0 =1.$

The solution of sequences $z_n$  is

$z(n)$ = 2 cos($2^n arccos(7/4)$) - 5/2

We now present z_n in a table and a plot respectively:

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iox0T.gif)

*Note that z_n are NOT integers for all n except $z_0$

[image]

Choose p=5, we have

$(z_n)_5$ = $z_n$ - floor($z_n$/5) *5

We now present $(z_n)_5$ in a table and a plot respectively:

To be continued here

image 7 here

image 8 here

Answer (score 0):

Can we drop the suggested choice of c by Wiki and choose

c ≠ $\frac{b^2−2b−8}{4a}$ instead?

The reason is that with wiki's choice of c, say a=1, b=5, c=7/4, none of $z_n$ will be

integers except n=0.

On the other hand, with a, b, c free except a>=1, b>=1 and c>=1 we have the nice property

that all $z_n$ are integers for all n.  For example a = b = c = 1 will be perfect for us as

all $z_n$ will be integers!!!.
.